Packaging Error when packing an google calendar api project pyinstaller
I'm working on a project and I'm using pyinstaller to package the application into an exe file. I tried to implement the google calendar API into the application but when I try to run the exe file it gives an error and I can't find why this would be happening.
Error:
AttributeError: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'

When I look in the site-packages in that directory that file exists and has a 'CredentialsWithTokenUri' function.
Would love any help! Let me know if you need any more info.
Application is also developed using customtkinter which is the library I'm using for display.

Are you saying your script runs without issues when you run it without packaging it, but you are getting this error only when you try to run the version packaged with PyInstaller? Are you sure the same version of Python and the API package are being used in both cases?

Yes, when I run the Python script normally it runs perfectly. When I run the packaged version of it, it breaks. I'm not sure if they are using the same version of python so I will have to test that out.

If you find the version of Python and the package match what you have in your test environment, you should probably come up with a small piece of code that demonstrates the issue - for example, a small script that accesses the API (of course without sharing your API key), so that people can try to reproduce your issue, or see what the issue might be.

I think I found that it didn't use the same python version, I'm testing right now if I can get the same error right now.

Did a little bit of testing and sure enough it was just my python version. Thanks for helping me!

You're welcome - if you think what you did might help another, consider writing and accepting an answer to your question. Otherwise, consider closing the question, so that it no longer appears as unanswered.
